# How do I run JOptionPane on EDT?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

I'm *still* having problems with blank `JOptionPane`s. Based on research at SO and in *Java Docs*, this obviously has something to do with not using the `EDT`.  My question is how exactly do the `EDT` and its methods apply to `JOptionPane`? For example, the terminal error output makes it quite clear that the `JOptionPane` below is not run on the `EDT`. What's missing specifically, and how does something like `Runnable` fit in?

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class PaneDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String[] TEXT ={
            //message
            "Hello, World!",
            //title
            "Greeting"};//end TEXT
    showMyPane(TEXT);
}//end main
public static void showMyPane(final String[] TEXT)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, TEXT[0], TEXT[1], 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
    {
        System.err.println("Err: GUI failed to use EDT.");
    }//end if(!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
}//end showMyPane
}//end class PaneDemo
```

An answer suggested adding `invokeLater`. That doesn't seem to render very well in BlueJ, however.

[image: BlueJ Screenshot]

Also isEventDispatchThread() is still returning the error in the terminal. Is that simply because it is now in the wrong location?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create `JOptionPane` on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) like this:

[image]

```
  final String[] TEXT = {
        //message
        "Hello, World!",
        //title
        "Greeting"};//end TEXT

     ...

    /**
     * Create GUI and components on Event-Dispatch-Thread
     */
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, TEXT[0] 
                      + "\n is on EDT: " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(), TEXT[1],
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
```

Have a look at the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)  it should help you understand what its all about

**UPDATE:**

as per comment you should initiate the `JOptionPane` on the `EDT` on each call in `showPane(...)` method like so:

```
   public static void showMyPane(final String[] TEXT) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, TEXT[0] 
                      + "\n is on EDT: " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(), TEXT[1],
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }//end showMyPane

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] TEXT = {
            //message
            "Hello, World!",
            //title
            "Greeting"};//end TEXT
        showMyPane(TEXT);
    }
```

Comment: `"However if you only want to show a JOptionPane without any JFrame etc you don't need to use Event-Dispatch-Thread"`, actually, yeah, I think you do.

Comment: @David If EDT is not required, what is causing the blank JOptionPanes? I've read Concurrency in Swing about Integer.MAX_VALUE times already.

Comment: You can also your SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait if you want to block the execution of the code until the user has responded to the dialog

Comment: David: only if its API says that it is. Last time I looked, this wasn't mentioned.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you are right just checked it now sorry another link mislead me

Comment: @MattB sorry I was incorrect about that, as for blank `JOptionPane`s I'm not sure, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). See my edited post

Comment: @David No worries! As for an SSCCE, it seems to occur entirely randomly, so the code I posted already is the best I can do.

Comment: @Andrew It'll only block with in the context if the EDT, it will allow the calling thread to continue running

Comment: So how does the code posted for this answer fit with the code I posted in the question? In other words, what changes do I now make to `showMyPane()`?

Comment: @MattB see update. BTW the Blank `JOptionPane` might have happened due to creating multiple `JOptionPane`s one after another without use of EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer not good idea to use `invokeAndWait`, if is there once time started EDT, `invokeLater` is safiest, otherwise have to test `isEvent...`, [because invokeAndWait lock EDT if is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769895/when-exactly-is-the-event-dispatch-thread-started/10770381#10770381) to try to call `invokeAndWait` on EDT

Comment: @mKorbel I agree, but if you've already made the choice to sync the call back to the EDT (because you've checked `isEventDispatchingThread`) and you're interested in the return result of the call, `invokeAndWait` is one of the best choices.

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason for `javax.swing.SwingUtilities` rather than simply `SwingUtilities`? The class compiles either way. I haven't tried to run it yet though.

Comment: @MattB it basically like an inline import, you wont have to still add the `imports javax.swing...` statement. You can optionally clarify the import globally just delete the `javax.swing.` part and then use this at top of class after package declaration `import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;`.

Comment: @MattB see my update you have the `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` outside of the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` thus it returns false